# How to disable certificate validation in client-side using Spring Boot Security

Tags: ssl-certificate

Well, I'm new to Spring Boot Security and I have a question. I have the simple settings to enable https on the server, as follows:

`server:
   port: 8443
   ssl:
     key-store-type: PKCS12
     key-store: classpath: keystore.p12
     key-store-password: mypass
     key-alias: testkey`

So far so good. The issue is that clients accessing the endpoints of that server, as a simple curl for example, receive certificate verification failure. From what I could read, the https communication is made over TSL (or SSL) and it requires the user to validate the certificate issued by the server to enable a security channel.

I did not want all clients to have to carry the certificate with them to access the endpoints, because it's a Rest API I'm developing.

Some urls of apis that enable https but do not require the certificate:

- https://api.github.com/*
- https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/*
- ...

What way should I follow in order to keep encryption enabled, ie keep **https**, but also not require client-side certificate validation?

PS: By the browser I can access my services and get the answers, but a java client, python, or the curl, does not work.

**EDIT** 
I did not want to set the client on the option to make the request insecure, I wanted to keep https but did not require the client to carry the certificate with him. Maybe I can not even do this, so I'm asking because I'm definitely a beginner. If there is no way to do it, I await an answer in that direction, more complete if possible

Comment: You already found the solution, you have to configure the client. If you want more informations, [edit] your question and say what client do you use. For cURL see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60750/does-curl-have-a-no-check-certificate-option-like-wget

Comment: Man, I did not want to set the client on the option to make the request insecure, I wanted to keep https but did not require the client to carry the certificate with him. Maybe I can not even do this, so I'm asking.

Comment: Your question is about certificate validation, but your comment is about carrying the certificate. What is your problem? As you already found out, you can disable validation. And why do you think, that the client carries the certificate? If you don't use one of the cached root certificates the client doesn't carry the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on each individual client. For example, you do this by ignoring the security warning in your browser. For curl, use `-k` or `--insecure` for wget use `--no-check-certificate`, you'll have to research how to ignore ssl in whatever client you are using. There is no way to control this from the server as that would defeat the entire purpose of SSL/TLS.

Comment: Repeating what I said to @dur: Man, I did not want to set the client on the option to make the request insecure, I wanted to keep https but did not require the client to carry the certificate with him. Maybe I can not even do this, so I'm asking.
If there is no way to do it, I await an answer in that direction, more complete if possible.

Comment: You misunderstand what TLS is and what these options do. If you don't register your certificate with a trusted authority there is no way for the client to know if it is secure or not. These options will still encrypt the transmission but the recipient is not verified.